# Sync files on upload with Fabric, possible?

Tags: python, ubuntu, fabric

I'm using fabric to deploy files to my server. This works by it creating a zip from git and unpacking it on the server. However, I noticed the all it does is overwrite and/or add any new files. If does not clean up redundant files no longer in the release. I know this is what git is for, but in the context of fabric/Ubuntu is it possible to see the content on the zip, compare, then remove files no longer in the new zip?

What Fabric does

```
> cd git archive --format=tar master | gzip > release.tar.gz;
Uploads to remote via Fabric
> cd 'www/'; tar -xzvf release.tar.gz;
```

Comment: why using `fabric`.Can you choose `rsync` ?

Comment: I have not heard of rsync, could I use it with Fabric?

Comment: `rsync` is using for synchronise between servers. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories-on-a-vps

Comment: If you want to go the rsync route, there is also a extension for rsync [link](http://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.0/api/contrib/project.html).

Comment: Why don't you just delete the directory on the server before unpacking it? This way you would clean up redundant files. But actually, why do you upload the zip at all. Couldn't you just do a git clone on the target server?